# QuickLook generator for markdown only recognises *.markdown

Tags: quicklook, markdown

I have started using markdown for simple texts, writing in TextWrangler. I am quite happy to use Finder and QuickLook to preview the file and have installed the [QLMarkdown.qlgenerator](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown) but it only works with files using the `markdown` extension. The `Info.plist` indicates that it should work with `mdown`, `md`, `text and more.

Does anyone know how to get QuickLook working?

Comment: I got this as a different fork and it works with .md for me. http://mdk.org.pl/2009/2/10/quicklook-for-markdown  Did you restart or logout? I think I had to at least logout/in for it to recognize .md

Comment: The version linked to above is older by some years but I tried it anyway. I logged out etc but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

The installation instructions say to run `qlmanage -r` in Terminal if it doesn't automatically start working. I just installed and didn't have to.